# How to do I mitigate diacetyl in cider that developed during secondary fermentation?

Tags: cider, contamination, secondary, diacetyl-rest

About 10 days after transferring a cider to secondary, it developed a faint diacetyl aroma.  I moved it to a warmer location (~70degF) for a few days for a diacetyl rest, but the smell is now more pronounced.

I am considering the following next steps:

1. If it is from bacteria, I am considering shocking it with campden and adding fresh yeast and a little sugar to allow the yeast to metabolize the diacetyl.
2. If it is from the yeast, I will give it more time unless there are other recommendations.
3. Toss it if it is beyond repair.  Diacetyl is the dominant aroma.

Background:

Yeast: Lalvin D 47

OG: 1.045

Cider: Pasteurized

Temp: 60 to 65degF

Two other batches started at the same time and temperatures but with different yeast (Nottingham Ale and Mangrove Jack M02) have not developed the issue.

Comment: I don't have a great answer- but don't dump a cider unless it's truly bad after like...a year. D47/Montrachet aren't my favorite for cider, they take a while to clean up and have an odd profile. Sit & forget and try it in another month or two (if you have the space to do so).  Sometimes they clean up and leave a really neat complex cider... and sometimes they're better ran through a still.

Answer (score 3):

Diacetyl is a normal part of most fermentations.  Nice thing is that yeast will eat it.  The yeast just needs time.  Give it 3-4 weeks of age, and the diacetyl should be cleaned up.  No fancy actions are needed, just patience.  If 4 weeks doesn't do it, wait a couple more weeks.  Keep the cider at a reasonable temperature, upper 50s to 70 F will work just fine.  When the diacetyl disappears, enjoy.